# How to get miniconda2 installation file from the miniconda website using a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, conda

I'd like to write a bash script which **automatically** downloads the miniconda installation script in `Linux-x86_64` for `python2.7`.

Apparently I have to go to the [website](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and manually download the installation file.

I can get slightly older version [here](https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/) which would give me `conda 4.5.12` version but from the miniconda [website](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) I get `conda 4.6.9`

Basically I want a function like below but instead of downloading [this file](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-4.5.12-Linux-x86_64.sh), I'd like to have the latest version. Thanks, Jen.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #Function to Download miniconda

    function download_miniconda() {

    url=http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-4.5.12-Linux-x86_64.sh
    wget -c "$url"           
 }
```

One work away around would be to run `conda update conda` after installing `4.5.12` but I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

If you open https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html in Firefox, you can right-click on the "64-bit (bash installer)" link there and select "Copy link location" and then paste that link somewhere, like in your download script. That gives the following link: https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh